# Android Threading Issue

Tags: android, timer, android-asynctask

I have the following code that I want to be able to loop every 30 seconds.

```
MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
    public LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult() {
        @Override
        public void gotLocation(final Location location) {
            GeoPoint myGeoPoint = new GeoPoint(
                    (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1000000),
                    (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1000000));
            myMapController.animateTo(myGeoPoint);
            myMapController.setZoom(10);

            lat = location.getLatitude();
            lon = location.getLongitude();

            new OverlayTask().execute();


            Timer timer;
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTimerTask(), 30000, 30000); 
        }

    };
```

Gets fired once I have the location, and the OverlayTask executes fine, it also will execute when assigned to a menu item to force it.

However inside the timer I get an error.

```
public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Log.i(">>>>>>>>>>>> Refresh: ", "Success");
            new OverlayTask().execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(">>>>>>>>>>>> Error executing MyAsyncTask: ", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

The error is....

> > Error executing MyAsyncTask:(2573): Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method:

```
public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    Log.i(">>>>>>>>>>>> Refresh: ", "Success");
                    new OverlayTask().execute();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(">>>>>>>>>>>> Error executing MyAsyncTask: ", e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```